# how to make iOS app connecting with bluetooth?

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, bluetooth

how to make iOS app with bluetooth?
I need an app which connects and exchange data via bluetooth with other devices, laptop for example.

Many packages for BLE and cant find for classic bluetooth

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use the classic Bluetooth interface of an Apple iOS device, you have to comply with/accept [Apple's MFi](https://mfi.apple.com/) licensing programme (Made for iPhone/iPod/iPad), which is a major hurdle and the reason for the lack of corresponding libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: you don't want classic Bluetooth for this. You want BLE. It supports everything you want for this kind of use case. See [Core Bluetooth](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth).

Much too long answer about classic Bluetooth and iPhones from my years building earbuds:

Continuing from Risto's answer, even with MFi certification (which requires adding an extra chip to your device, not just licensing), you still don't get general access to the BR/EDR ("classic") interface. You only get access to iAP2, which is an SPP-like serial protocol, but is not SPP. If you're porting from Android, you probably are using SPP, and sorry, that's just not available. You're going to need to switch to BLE.

MFi certification is a useful if you build an audio device that also needs a non-audio control channel. It makes it easy to ensure that both the audio connection and control connection are connected to the same device. This is extremely difficult to do with BLE. But iAP2 isn't a particularly nice protocol, and has weird corner cases. You should not go through the cost and trouble of MFi just to get a SPP-like serial protocol.

On iPhones, access to BR/EDR non-audio profiles is limited to the proprietary iAP2 and GATT over BR/EDR (which is less useful than it sounds since most chips don't support it). Classic audio profiles are limited to what Apple's audio frameworks support, which is not very flexible.

If you make a Bluetooth audio device, have a little extra room on your board, enough margin to add a chip to your BOM, and your SoC supports it, MFi is definitely worth exploring. You can improve the pairing experience marginally and it makes it a bit easier to manage an extra control channel. Plus, you get to add that "Made for iPhone" logo to your packaging. For hearing aids (which I have less experience with), I expect that MFi is a must-have today. From my casual investigation, it looks like it adds some really nice capabilities.

For everyone else, you want BLE.