# Is there an alternative for flutter-bluetooth-serial package that can be used on both IOS and Android devices?

Tags: flutter, dart, bluetooth, flutter-dependencies, ios-bluetooth

I have been working on a flutter app for few months now. The main feature that my app relying on is Bluetooth serial communication. Basically my app will connect and communicate (receive and send data) to HC-06 Bluetooth module that is connected with a microcontroller.
Everything was going great till the moment when I found out that flutter bluetooth serial package doesn’t actually work with Ios devices (have been doing all tests on android device).
So I’m wondering if there is a way to make it work on ios devices or if there is any alternative way that I can use to creat the serial communication between ios and Hc-06 device.

Comment: This question comes up here every now and then. This is my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69446219/8124605).

Comment: I went through your answer. Does that mean I need to get certified from apple mfi to be able to communicate with third party hardware devices and if so do you have any idea if it’s something can be obtained easily?

Comment: You don't want to go down this road. The MFi program requires additional hardware that will cost you more than upgrading the HC-06 to BT4 module. It is absolutely not something that can be obtained easily.

Comment: @RobNapier  I thought *which is a major hurdle and the reason for the lack of corresponding libraries.* would also explain that, but apparently that was not clear enough. Learned something again :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

iOS does not support SPP (Serial Port Profile), which is the serial protocol you are almost certainly using with Android. You will need to redesign your system to use another protocol.

The [HC-06](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/306/hc06-1324356.pdf) only supports Bluetooth 2.0+EDR, and I don't believe there is any protocol it can handle that is also supported by iOS (in a way accessible to developers). You would likely need to use a module that supports BLE GATT, which requires Bluetooth 4.

(iOS does support GATT over BR/EDR, but I don't believe that's available on the HC-06.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I truly appreciate it. I think I have no choice but to change the Bluetooth module I’m using and redesign my system.

Answer (score 0):

taha! I recommend you to try this package [flutter_blue](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_blue).
I use it to connect my BLE device and communicate well.

Comment: Thanks for your response! The problem with this package is that it’s for Low energy Bluetooth devices which doesn’t accommodate to my case (Hc-06 Bluetooth device). The other problem is that it doesn’t support  a serial communication, from what I saw it can only read characteristics (correct me if I’m wrong).