# How can I send data to HC-06 with flutter bluetooth

Tags: flutter, bluetooth

I am trying to send data to HC-06 but I don't know how.Can Someone help me about this issue?

Comment: [this](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bluetooth_serial) package may help

Comment: Note that this is only possible for Android. flutter_bluetooth_serial cannot work on iOS, and I don't believe there is any protocol that both iOS and the HC-06 support. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/72953015/97337